# Event handling between C++ and Objective C

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, events

I recently started working on an iOS game and decided to write a distinct part of the project in C++. This approach seems to work fine as long as the Objective C classes simply access some members or call functions on the C++ objects. However i can't seem to find an elegant way to make my Objective C classes respond to 'events' in the C++ classes. Any event handling system that uses callbacks seems out of the question (since Objective C methods and C++ functions and probably not interchangeable). All i can think of is using the delegate pattern and writing wrapper classes around my C++ delegate classes so i can use them in Objective C code. So my question is: Is there a better way of doing this?

NB:
I would like to prevent using Objective C directly in my C++ files, since these classes are supposed to be platform independent.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to consider the mechanism that CoreVideo uses.

In their model, they have a mechanism which involves registering a C callback function( http://tinyurl.com/axtxajf ), and one of the parameters to this function is a void*, which can be typecast to the Objective-C class you need access to.

Here is an example of a C function you may implement in your C++ modules to register the callback function. The parameter are the callback function and the pointer to the class instance:

```
SetEventCallback(EventCallbackFunction, self);
```

When the event needs to be handled, the callback function is called, and you can typecast the void* to call Obj-C class and invoke the method:

```
void EventCallbackFunction(void* objCPtr)
{
    [(MyObjCClass*)objCPtr someMethod];
}
```

Comment: Footnote: under ARC, bridge casts would have to be used to cast to and away from `void *`.

Comment: In this case the overhead/wrapping would consist of a lot of C callback functions that only pass their arguments to a corresponding objective c method. Using anonymous/lambda functions instead of separate C functions might be interesting though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use C++0x lambda functions, they are interchangeable (assignable to each other) with Objective-C blocks.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning lambda functions. I had no idea these exist (still learning C++ and Objective C). Imo the ultimate solution would be some kind of templates event class that allows me to define events like "anEvent<int, SomeObject*, bool>" with overloaded operators for registering handlers and calling the event. Lambda functions or objective C blocks might save me the overhead of wrapping my objective C method calls in C functions or separate classes. Since i'm still learning i have no way of quickly implementing this solution. Guess i have some studying to do first.